# Facing an error "Exception in thread main java.lang.nullpointerexception" in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am a newbie to selenium . Facing an error mentioned above.
Here is the code:-

"

```
package e3;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class Login {
     public WebDriver drv;
    public WebDriver firefox= new FirefoxDriver();

public void new_account()
{

    firefox.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Create New User']")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(drv,30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("user-username"))).isDisplayed();
    firefox.findElement(By.id("user-username")).sendKeys("testone");

    firefox.findElement(By.id("user-password")).sendKeys("polaris");

    firefox.findElement(By.id("confirmPassword")).sendKeys("polaris");

    firefox.findElement(By.name("Account.name")).sendKeys("test");

    firefox.findElement(By.name("Account.surname")).sendKeys("one");

    firefox.findElement(By.name("saveform")).click();

}

public static void main (String args[])
{
Login login=new Login();    
login.open_url();
login.open_group();
//login.Addnew_group();
login.new_account();

}
}
```

In this above code i am trying to open a new account and save it . In web when it opens up the desired page , the Loading sign appears so i inserted an explicit wait . Now it is showing me an error of 'Null pointer" .
Please help me out in rectifying this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: Why isn't this tagged Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a driver called firefox in your code, but for the wait you have added a driver called drv. This driver is not initialised which causes the error.

You want the wait to work for the driver you are actually using. I think the following adjustment will make it work for you:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(firefox,30);
```